# Apple Watch - Deep link? URL Scheme?

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, watchos

after looking for this a bunch, i couldin't find how to know ( if it is permitted by Apple ) what are the URL Scheme or Deep Link for some default apps from Apple Watch.
Let me explain:
I builded an Apple Watch app, and i whant to open another app, like, "Heart Rate".
I want to open this app on Apple Watch from my Apple Watch app.

*If i'll build this on iOS ( iPhone ) and want to open Message app, it has an `sms:` scheme and then i can open this app on iPhone.*

Now, on Apple Watch i dont know how to get this URL Scheme for Heart Rate, Breathe or Weather, i.e. the defaults Apple Watch.

Thanks

Comment: Not yet, i dont know if it is open by Apple